# Why the kernel is a normal subgroup?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $G$ be a group acting on a nonempty set $A$. Why the kernel of the action is a normal subgroup of $G$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\;\phi:G\to H\;$ be a group homomorphism, and let $\;x\in\ker\phi\;,\;\;g\in G\;$ , then

$$\phi(g^{-1}xg)=\phi(g^{-1})\phi(x)\phi(g)=\phi(g)^{-1}\cdot1\cdot\phi(g)=\phi(g)^{-1}\phi(g)=1\implies$$

$g^{-1}xg\in \ker\phi\;$ whenever $\;x\in\ker\phi\;,\;\;g\in G\;\iff\;\ker\phi\lhd G$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I mean kernel of a group action instead of a group homomorphism.

Comment: @Tony, if I understand you correctly then it is exactly the same: any group $\;G\;$ acting on a set $\;X\;$ determines uniquely a homomorphism $\;G\to S_X\;$, the kernel of which is called the group action's kernel.

Comment: Thanks very much! That is just where I don't understand. But do you mean $g^{-1}xg\in ker(G)\;$ instead of $g^{-1}xg\in G\;$?

Comment: Yes I do, @Tony: thay was a typo. Corrected now

Comment: @Tony If you want to interpret this entirely in terms of group actions, just replace $\phi(g)$ everywhere as the map $a\mapsto g\cdot a$.

Comment: In fact, "a group homomorphism $G\to S_X$"  is one possible definition of a group action of $G$ on $X$.